# I want to pass hashmap from custom arrayadapter to activity?

Tags: android

I want to pass HashMap or ArrayList Object from Custom ArrayAdapter to activity which fills the ListView.I want to send checked records recordId field.I m new To Android.Any Suggestion Plz

Comment: What do you means by `custom ArrayAdapter to activity?`

Comment: yes object in custom array adapter to activity

Answer (score 2):

Pass the adapter a reference to the activity. Then provide a method in the activity that the adapter can call.

In adapter:

```
private MyActivity activity;

public void setActivity(MyActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

In Activity:

```
// create adapter
adapter.setActvity(this);
```

In adapter (when you want to pass parameters back to activity):

```
activity.setHashMap(mymap);
```

Comment: but adpater not expose that method. setActivity in activity

Comment: Sir actually i m trying customListView on checked of checked box i stored selected record id in hashmap/object.now i want to send this hashmap/object to my main activity when user click button to show details.

Comment: Um, yes. You need to write that method and add it to your adapter. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful then you should accept one. If none of the answers were helpful, but you solved the problem, then you should answer the question yourself and then accept your own answer. That helps the community.

Answer (score 0):

**My CustomAdapter Class::**
    class SearchResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    private ArrayList<SearchResultModel> results;

    public SearchResultAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<SearchResultModel> results) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, results);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = convertView;
        SearchResultHolder holder=null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitemrow, null);
            holder = new SearchResultHolder();
            holder.jobdetails = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.jobdetails);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (SearchResultHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        SearchResultModel model = results.get(position);

        if (model != null)
        {
          row.setId(Integer.parseInt(model.getjob_id()));   
          String result=
                  "<font color=#5D2E8C>"+model.getjob_title()+"</font><br>" +
                  "<font color=#737373>"+model.getpost_date()+"</font><br>"+model.getuser_name()+"<br>" +
                  "<font color=#3C5A98>"+model.getsalary()+" Rs (Per Annum)</font><br>"+
                  "<font color=#97AB40>"+model.getjob_location()+"," +
                  " "+model.getjob_exp_min()+"-"+model.getjob_exp_max()+" year";
          holder.jobdetails.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));

        }
        return row;
    }

    class SearchResultHolder
    {
        TextView jobdetails;
    }
}
```

**My ListView in the Main Method That would use the Above ArrayAdapter.**

```
SearchResultAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;  
adapter=new SearchResultAdapter(this, R.layout.listitemrow, model);  
//Here model is the ArrayList<SearchResultModel> 
lv=getListView();
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int arg2, long arg3) 
    {  
    }
}
```

**My SearchResultModel Class**

```
package com.cws.model;

public class SearchResultModel {

    private String job_id,userdetail_id,user_name,subuser_id,
                        job_title,search_keyword,job_skill,
                        job_exp_min,job_exp_max,
                        job_description,salary,
                        job_location,education,
                        industry_id,role_id,functional_id,job_type,
                        desire_candiadate_profile,company_profile,
                        website,executive_name,address,email,
                        phone,post_date,is_active;
    private String count,counter;//----count=total no of row found
                                                //---counter=now displaying row nos.

    private String errorflag;

    public void seterrorflag(String errorflag)
    {
        this.errorflag=errorflag;
    }
    public String geterrorflag()
    {
        return this.errorflag;
    }


    public void setcount(String count)
    {
        this.count=count;
    }
    public String getcount()
    {
        return this.count;
    }
    public void setcounter(String counter)
    {
        this.counter=counter;
    }
    public String getcounter()
    {
        return this.counter;
    }
    public void setjob_id(String job_id)
    {
        this.job_id=job_id;
    }
    public String getjob_id()
    {
        return this.job_id;
    }
    public void setuserdetail_id(String userdetail_id){
        this.userdetail_id=userdetail_id;
    }
    public String getuserdetail_id()
    {
        return this.userdetail_id;
    }

    public void setuser_name(String user_name){
        this.user_name=user_name;
    }
    public String getuser_name()
    {
        return this.user_name;
    }

    public void setsubuser_id(String subuser_id){
        this.subuser_id=subuser_id;
    }
    public String getsubuser_id()
    {
        return this.subuser_id;
    }
    public void setjob_title(String job_title){
        this.job_title=job_title;
    }
    public String getjob_title()
    {
        return this.job_title;
    }
    public void setsearch_keyword(String search_keyword){
        this.search_keyword=search_keyword;
    }
    public String getsearch_keyword()
    {
        return this.search_keyword;
    }
    public void setjob_skill(String job_skill){
        this.job_skill=job_skill;
    }
    public String getjob_skill()
    {
        return this.job_skill;
    }
    public void setjob_exp_min(String job_exp_min){
        this.job_exp_min=job_exp_min;
    }
    public String getjob_exp_min()
    {
        return this.job_exp_min;
    }
    public void setjob_exp_max(String job_exp_max){
        this.job_exp_max=job_exp_max;
    }
    public String getjob_exp_max()
    {
        return this.job_exp_max;
    }
    public void setjob_description(String job_description){
        this.job_description=job_description;
    }
    public String getjob_description()
    {
        return this.job_description;
    }
    public void setsalary(String salary){
        this.salary=salary;
    }
    public String getsalary()
    {
        return this.salary;
    }
    public void setjob_location(String job_location){
        this.job_location=job_location;
    }
    public String getjob_location()
    {
        return this.job_location;
    }
    public void seteducation(String education){
        this.education=education;
    }
    public String geteducation()
    {
        return this.education;
    }
    public void setindustry_id(String industry_id){
        this.industry_id=industry_id;
    }
    public String getindustry_id()
    {
        return this.industry_id;
    }
    public void setrole_id(String role_id){
        this.role_id=role_id;
    }
    public String getrole_id()
    {
        return this.role_id;
    }
    public void setfunctional_id(String functional_id){
        this.functional_id=functional_id;
    }
    public String getfunctional_id()
    {
        return this.functional_id;
    }
    public void setjob_type(String job_type){
        this.job_type=job_type;
    }
    public String getjob_type()
    {
        return this.job_type;
    }
    public void setdesire_candiadate_profile(String desire_candiadate_profile){
        this.desire_candiadate_profile=desire_candiadate_profile;
    }
    public String getdesire_candiadate_profile()
    {
        return this.desire_candiadate_profile;
    }
    public void setcompany_profile(String company_profile){
        this.company_profile=company_profile;
    }
    public String getcompany_profile()
    {
        return this.company_profile;
    }
    public void setwebsite(String website){
        this.website=website;
    }
    public String getwebsite()
    {
        return this.website;
    }
    public void setexecutive_name(String executive_name){
        this.executive_name=executive_name;
    }
    public String getexecutive_name()
    {
        return this.executive_name;
    }
    public void setaddress(String address){
        this.address=address;
    }
    public String getaddress()
    {
        return this.address;
    }
    public void setemail(String email){
        this.email=email;
    }
    public String getemail()
    {
        return this.email;
    }
    public void setphone(String phone){
        this.phone=phone;
    }
    public String getphone()
    {
        return this.phone;
    }
    public void setpost_date(String post_date){
        this.post_date=post_date;
    }
    public String getpost_date()
    {
        return this.post_date;
    }
    public void setis_active(String is_active){
        this.is_active=is_active;
    }
    public String getis_active()
    {
        return this.is_active;
    }

}
```

Comment: thnx but my scenario is different.i want to pass object from custom array adapter to my main activity.

Comment: Are You invoking the custom adapter from your main activity??

Comment: thank u Androider.My problem solved.using suggestions.U Guys ROCKS